# django-social-auth create new user programmatically by facebook_id

Tags: django, django-socialauth

Is there any way to create User and UserSocialAuth objects without actually loggin in but only having FACEBOOK_ID of a user you want to create an account for?

I'm creating a simple app where user can select a friend from FB and create some model object for him. Since I have reference to User entity I need to have it whether that friend has been registered or not. And if not I need to create the whole object graph programmatically. It is possible to do using standard functionality of django-social-auth or should I create records in 'auth_user' and 'social_auth_usersocialauth' by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this custom backend that sets the username to the person's FACEBOOK_ID.

```
from social_auth.backends.facebook import FacebookBackend
class IDFacebookBackend(FacebookBackend):
    """Facebook OAuth2 authentication backend"""
    def get_user_details(self, response):
        """Return user details from Facebook account"""
        return {'username': response.get('id'),
                'email': response.get('email', ''),
                'fullname': response.get('name', ''),
                'first_name': response.get('first_name', ''),
                'last_name': response.get('last_name', '')}
```

Use this version of `get_username` in your auth pipleline instead of `social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username`

```
def get_username(details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    " Make Username from User Id "
    if user:
        return {'username': UserSocialAuth.user_username(user)}
    else:
        return details['username']
```

Your pipeline should look like this:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'our_custom_auth.get_username', # <= This should be the previous function
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details'
)
```

Then all you need to do is call `User.objects.create(username=friends_facebook_id)` and you have a User that cannot login with username/pass, but can be referenced easily through ForeignKey fields.

Also, when that "Friend" comes and joins up with your site at a later date (Using SocialAuth), they will automatically be given this User object and your internal graph will stay accurate.

Comment: Hi, now I'm trying to implement it and it doesn't work. First it complains that UserSocialAuth doesn't have user_username (I'm using Django 1.5.1) At this point my db was populated with existing users. Then I recreated the schema and now it doesn't even reach 'get_username' method and get this: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 66, in authenticate
    user.backend = "%s.%s" % (backend.__module__, backend.__class__.__name__)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'backend'

Comment: Please, create a new question and include a stack trace, and I'll help you through it. Reply to this comment with a link to the new question.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the idea described above but with less effort and eventually I ended up with the following:

I overrode `associate_by_email` stage from `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` to my own implementation of  `associate_by_username`. Since username is unique in Django auth we can use that.
So totally changes are

1. Implement `associate_by_username`

   from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned, ObjectDoesNotExist
   from social_auth.exceptions import AuthException
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   def associate_by_username(details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
   """Return user entry with same email address as one returned on details."""
       if user:
           return None

   ```
   username = details.get('username')

   if username:
       try:
           return {'user': User.objects.get(username=username)}
       except MultipleObjectsReturned:
           raise AuthException(kwargs['backend'], 'Not unique email address.')
       except ObjectDoesNotExist:
           pass
   ```
2. Then I add this method to pipeline

   SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
   'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
   'core.auth.associate_by_username',
   'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username',
   'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
   'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
   'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
   'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
   )
3. And when I need to get user I look it up by facebookId (`recipient = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(uid=target_facebook_id)`
   ) but create by facebookUsername (`User(username=target_username)`)